# Export A Dashboard as an Image

Tags: export

I've created myself a nice looking dashboard as a combination of different web parts within a web part page, the only problem now is that when I try to put this in a monthly stakeholder pack, I have to print screen and crop the quicklaunch / top link bar etc to paste it in to powerpoint.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could export it easier / better - maybe something like a button that exports the page as an image?

Thanks for your help

Rob

Comment: Is this a SharePoint question? In my opinion, this probably is a question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You can export the page as a PDF using a third [party product](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/convert-html-pages-to-pdf-format-using.html).

Alternatively use the Snipping tool in windows which allows you to just drag a rectangle over your browser window.

Please note that I worked on this 3rd party product so the usual disclaimers apply.

Answer (score 1):

Snipping Tool build into Vista/Win 7 is my usual tool of choice.  [SnagIT](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/default.asp) is a popular alternative.